# What is the lifetime of a property with only a getter

Tags: c#, .net

Lets assume I instantiated `MyClass`. Does my Foo property have a reference at this point or is it null? Also what happens after I call `UseFoo()` and exit the scope? Did I dispose Foo or just foo?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly string param;
    private IDisposable Foo => new Foo(param);

    public MyClass(string param)
    {
        this.param = param;
    }

    public void UseFoo()
    {
        using var foo = Foo;
        // use foo
    }
}
```

Comment: You should think of `Foo` more as a method than a field.

Comment: Note that "only a getter" is not really important to answer your question. The important part is what that getter does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q: Does my Foo property have a reference at this point or is it null?**
**A:** No, because the property does not have a backing field, aka state.

Instead, every time you read the value of `Foo`, you will construct a new instance of the `Foo` type and return that.

As [@juharr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302918/juharr) so nicely put it in their comment, it is a property but behaves like a method.

**Q: Also what happens after I call UseFoo() and exit the scope? Did I dispose Foo or just foo?**
**A:** You disposed the single object that you got from reading the `Foo` property and stored in the `foo` local variable.

Since the `Foo` property does not actually have state, you only disposed the object that was constructed for you when you read the `Foo` property.

The next time you read the `Foo` property you will get a new instance.

Comment: So after I exit UseFoo() there will be not a single reference to Foo object in memory, is that right?

Comment: That's not so easy to answer. Disposing of an object does not garbage collect it. After you exit `UseFoo`, and if you have no *other* references to any `Foo` instance, then whichever `Foo` instances still in memory are now eligible for garbage collection. That's about as exact I can get.

Answer (score 2):

I find it helpful to mentally translate `=>` to "returns". It is an active operation, not a passive assignment. So in your case, I would read it as *"Foo returns a new foo of param"*.

When it comes to properties,

```
private IDisposable Foo => new foo(param);
```

is equivalent to

```
private IDisposable Foo
{
    get { return new foo(param); }
}
```